# PHP overwrite method and call the overwritten in same class

Tags: php, class

I have a class given by an external developer. He could update his class whenever he wants.
One of his method, e.g. "getArray", returns me an Array directly with important information in it.

```
class externalDevDudesClass 
{
    public function getArray
    {
        return array(
            'example' => 'important information';
        );
    }
}
```

I'd like to add some information to the given array. 
I have the possibility to copy and overwrite any method of his class but then I don't have the new information coming on an update.
Ye, I could create a child of his class but I can't update the code where it creates objects of the class "externalDevDudesClass". So my question is: is there a possibility to add additional informations to this array by calling the method "getArray"? Maybe by working with an class_alias or something?

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a solution. Extends his class and add your information to the return value of parent::getArray()

```
class MyClass extends externalDevDudesClass {
    public function getArray() {
        $parentValue = parent::getArray();
        return array_merge($parentValue, ['my' => 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as i said: I can't update the code where it creates instances of "externalDevDudesClass". I think your solution needs an instance of the class "MyClass", right? :/

Comment: yes it needs its instance. In case you cannot create instance of MyClass, there is no solution where externalDevDudesClass could return other value :/ Think of better OOP design